# Combine Column Wrap Text, Color and Column Width - JSON Code

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, json-formatting, column-formatting

**I have the wrap code:**

```
{ "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style":{
        "white-space":"wrap"
  }, 
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

**I have the color code and column width code**

```
    { "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
     "elmType": "div",
     "txtContent": "@currentField",
     "style": {"color": "green","width": "300px"}
 }
```

*Can someone please help me to combine the two so they work, I tried a few things no luck.  Tks.*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following JSON, it shall work for you.

```
    { "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json", 
     "elmType": "div", 
     "style":{ "white-space":"wrap","color": "green","width": "300px" },
     "txtContent": "@currentField" 
    }
```

In fact as you set the width to 300px, it makes the wrap not work as you thought. You may try to use a smaller width value for it.

Comment: Thank You!  I will give it a try, I realized I had style twice, but this is great!

Comment: @Aspen Just let us know if you have any further question.

Answer (score 0):

Use below combined JSON code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "white-space": "wrap",
        "color": "green",
        "width": "300px"
    }
}
```

**Note**:

1. It is better to use latest version (v2) of column-formatting JSON schema.
2. You can add multiple CSS properties in single `style` property of JSON.

Go through below official documentation of column formatting. It will help you to better understand it:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint - Style](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#style)

Comment: Thank You!  I will give it a try, I realized I had style twice, but this is great!

Comment: Sure, try and let me know if this works for you or not.